# The users who have already logged in cant login anymore

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How can I stop the users who have already logged in cant login any more?

I tried to make a variable equal to `True`

when the user is logged in and make an **if** statement But it didnt work

```
if islogin == True:
   print("You are already logged in!")
```

Heres my code

```
import json
def login():
    user = input("Enter your user name: ")
    passw = input("Enter your password: ")
    with open("info.json") as f:
        dct = json.load(f)
    if user in dct and dct[user] == passw:
        print("Login succesful!")
    else:
        print("Error! Incorrect username or password.")
    return

while True:
    demand = input("What do you want to do? ")
    if demand == "login":
        login()

    elif demand == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: : Can you share your input screen screenshot.  You may need to end your True condition if the user is a valid one like something `break` or `false`

Comment: : You create some list and check if user already exist does not allow again him as in list

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips to debug your code. Tip: how does the file `"info.json"` get updated?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `unique user` try to create a `global list` for `logged user` somting like this:

```
import json
logged_user=[]
def login():
    global logged_user
    user = input("Enter your user name: ")
    passw = input("Enter your password: ")
    with open("info.json") as f:
        dct = json.load(f)
    if user in dct and dct[user] == passw and user not in logged_user:
        print("Login succesful!")
        logged_user.append(user)
    else:
        print("Error! Incorrect username or password or .....")
    return

while True:
    demand = input("What do you want to do? ")
    if demand == "login":
        login()

    elif demand == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```